# Can the new csproj file structure be used with a ASP.NET Framework project?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-2.0, csproj

The new .csproj format includes some significant improvements over the classic files, including tight integration with NuGet package management and significantly less-verbose structure. I want to gain these benefits whilst still using the .NET Framework 4.6 and ASP.NET (because my project depends on Umbraco which has yet to produce a .NET Core version).

The biggest challenge would seem to be the debugging experience - an ASP.NET Core project expects to run a dotnet core application and set up a reverse proxy to an IIS instance. This process is completely alien to the .NET Framework model and I wouldn't know where to start trying to set up debugging in Visual Studio.

Is there any way to get these two project models to mix?

Comment: You are focussing on an IIS web project now not any console .net framework application?

Comment: cool question i havent tried, but i think this could work. as far as i know the 'new' project structure gets completely rewritten to old structure by `.prop` files. unless the old tags are invalid this would still work. atleast definitly for console and class projects.

Comment: This is specifically: can I get an **ASP.NET Framework** project to build and debug from Visual Studio whilst using the new .csproj file format? If there are things which *also* work for console applications and other hosting mechanisms, that's great too.

Comment: Does this match your scenario? this link explains some have and have nots for doing such: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/choosing-core-framework-server#current-net-framework-applications

Answer (score 80, accepted):

There is a bunch of open issues on GitHub regarding support of new csproj format for ASP.NET (non-Core) applications. Some of them:

- [Using the new .Csproj without .Net core #1688](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/1688)
- [Add support for ASP.NET (non-Core) projects #2670](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/2670)
- [Support for "classic" ASP.NET #1978](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1978)

As you probably already understood, new csproj format is not yet supported for ASP.NET applications. It's possible to make it work, however it won't be smooth.

Some time ago I have tried to create ASP.NET MVC project in new csproj format, just for fun. I made it work, however I had not played with it a lot. So it will be interesting to know your experience.

The steps are following:

1. Remove old unrequired project files:

   - MvcApplication.csproj
   - MvcApplication.csproj.user
   - packages.config
2. Create new MvcApplication.csproj with the following content:

   ```
   <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

     <PropertyGroup>
       <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
     </PropertyGroup>

     <PropertyGroup>
       <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
       <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
     </PropertyGroup>

     <ItemGroup>
       <PackageReference Include="Antlr" version="3.4.1.9004" />
       <PackageReference Include="bootstrap" version="3.0.0" />
       <PackageReference Include="jQuery" version="1.10.2" />
       <PackageReference Include="jQuery.Validation" version="1.11.1" />
       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" version="2.2.0" />
       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.Intercept" version="2.0.6" />
       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector" version="2.2.0" />
       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector" version="2.2.0" />
       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web" version="2.2.0" />
       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer" version="2.2.0" />
       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel" version="2.2.0" />
       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" />
       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" />
       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" />
       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" />
       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="1.0.5" />
       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" Version="4.4.1" />
       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="3.2.3" />
       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="2.1.0" developmentDependency="true" />
       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" />
       <PackageReference Include="Modernizr" version="2.6.2" />
       <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.4" />
       <PackageReference Include="Respond" version="1.2.0" />
       <PackageReference Include="WebGrease" version="1.5.2" />
     </ItemGroup>

     <ItemGroup>
       <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
     </ItemGroup>

     <ItemGroup>
       <Reference Include="System.Web" />
     </ItemGroup>

     <ItemGroup>
       <Compile Update="Global.asax.cs">
         <DependentUpon>Global.asax</DependentUpon>
       </Compile>
     </ItemGroup>

     <ItemGroup>
       <Content Include="Web.config">
         <SubType>Designer</SubType>
       </Content>
       <Content Include="Web.*.config">
         <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
         <SubType>Designer</SubType>
       </Content>
     </ItemGroup>

   </Project>
   ```

   The long package list above includes default packages added for default ASP.NET MVC application. You should add other packages used by your application.

   Don't forget to add the `Microsoft.CSharp` package, otherwise you'll get following compilation error on `ViewBag` assignments:

   > error CS0656: Missing compiler required member
   >   'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo.Create'

   In ASP.NET projects, `Microsoft.CSharp` is added as reference to the project. But it's better to consume it as NuGet package.

   The only direct reference that could not be avoided is a `System.Web`.
3. Debugging the project

   You were right when said that debugging could be a pain. Since Visual Studio does not know it's an ASP.NET application, there is no instant method to start debugging session.

   I see 2 possible solutions here:

   a. Use IIS Express for debugging.

   It's quite easy to configure debugging based on IIS Express executable. Just create the following debugging profile:

   [image]

   Corresponding launchSettings.json:

   ```
   {
     "profiles": {
       "ASP.NET Old csproj": {
         "commandName": "Executable",
         "executablePath": "c:\\Program Files\\IIS Express\\iisexpress.exe",
         "commandLineArgs": "/path:\"$(SolutionDir)$(ProjectName)\" /port:12345"
       }
   }
   ```

   b. Use IIS for debugging.

   In IIS Manager create application that points to directory with your project. Now you could debug your application by attaching to `w3wp.exe` process.

Here is [**Sample Project on GitHub**](https://github.com/CodeFuller/stackoverflow/tree/Q47915353-New-Csproj-For-ASP.NET). It is basically default ASP.NET MVC project migrated to new csproj format following above steps. It could be compiled, executed and debugged (profile for IIS Express included)

Comment: That's a nice approach for using IIS Express. The only thing missing from being a perfect solution is how ASP.NET Core uses a "wwwroot" folder to contain all the static assets, where this still uses the project root. I assume a change to the `/path` switch when launching the application would be an answer.

Comment: Not sure I understood you correctly. Yes, ASP.NET Core changed the handling of static files and now all static content resides in [wwwroot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files). It's just a location used by ASP.NET Core Web Host by default. However it does not relate to csproj file structure. And since we discuss ASP.NET (non-Core), `wwwroot` does not come into play here. All ASP.NET static content folders (like `Content`, `fonts`, `Scripts`) have the same relative location within both project directory and directory of deployed application .

Comment: It's important because "source" files (anything outside of `wwwroot`) aren't used as part of the application, which makes it much easier to work with content-processors like webpack. I don't think the ASP.NET Framework build process particularly cares where files are, as long as they're in the project structure somewhere, but I was never able to set the application to run using `wwwroot` as the virtual directory of the site when running under the .NET Framework. Using the `/path` switch might be the answer I am looking for.

Comment: I had to change app args to this: `/path:$(SolutionDir)$(ProjectName) /port:1234` otherwise it wouldn't start. For some reason the quotes around the path wouldn't work. `"/path:$(SolutionDir)$(ProjectName)" /port:1234` worked too.

Comment: This also appears to break web publishing — it only seems to offer a folder target now, not stuff like WebDeploy.

Comment: The app args described in this solution and information from @skb did not work for me. I had to use the real full path to get it working.

Comment: Did anyone manage to deploy this via the command line? `dotnet publish` doesn't seem to produce valid output. The sample project gives me a 403 error when running inside iis express.

Comment: `<AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>` and `<OutputPath>bin</OutputPath>` was why my IIS couldn't find my DLLs. IIS looks in `.\bin` and not `.\bin\DebugOrRelease\net451`

Comment: @CodeFuller can you update your very nice answer with the latest changes meanwhile. Full support is still missing

Comment: I got this all to work, except VS doesn't seem to pick up the namespaces in the web.config file in the views folder, so I get all red squigles when editing a razor view... Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @ilivewithian I already deployed using msbuild before I changed the project format, and everything still seems to work fine that way (msbuild /p:DeployOnBuild=True)

Comment: How do you debug httpS localhost?

Comment: @CodeFuller FYI, your github project is missing the launchSettings.json file. you had it in the .gitignore

Answer (score 18):

I am following [this github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/2670#issuecomment-740837305) regarding this, and the latest comments posted add the last missing pieces. Basically, with a .csproj file like this:

```
<Project>
  <Import Project="Sdk.props" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
    <PublishProfileImported>true</PublishProfileImported>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectCapability Include="DotNetCoreWeb" />
    <ProjectCapability Include="SupportsSystemWeb" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <!-- add your packagereference/content/etc includes here -->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">15.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <!-- order is important! -->
  <Import Project="Sdk.targets" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" />
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
</Project>
```

everything works!

- The normal run and debug experience with visual studio starting iisexpress with the right applicationhost.config. If you fill out the sslport in launchsettings, it even works with ssl.
- The normal edit and debug razor experience without any red squiggles and with working intellisense/autocomplete.

The only thing that still seems to be missing is right click deploy functionality... But as you can use `msbuild /p:DeployOnBuild=True` to deploy, I finally don't see anything missing anymore that stops me from upgrading.

Comment: +1 if this question were asked in 2020 / 2021, this should be the accepted answer! wish i had read it first.

Comment: I needed to add `<Reference Include="System.Web" />` and `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" Version="5.2.7" />` for my project to build.

Comment: This builds and the website runs for me. When I try to run and debug it in visual studio though, I get the error "Unable to run your project. The "RunCommand" property is not defined."

Comment: @GarrettBanuk - for the 'Unable to run your project. The "RunCommand" property is not defined' issue, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71016227) worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to migrate ASP.NET MVC to new csproj format is using [try-convert](https://github.com/dotnet/try-convert) using the following command:

```
try-convert -p .\project.csproj --keep-current-tfms --no-backup --force-web-conversion
```

Thanks to the `--keep-current-tfms` option your target framework will not change.

After that you should change project SDK to [MSBuild.SDK.SystemWeb](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSBuild.SDK.SystemWeb) because the default SDK doesn't support old ASP.NET MVC.

```xml
<Project Sdk="MSBuild.SDK.SystemWeb/4.0.66">
```

Thanks to `MSBuild.SDK.SystemWeb` you should be able to use every function of VS in the same way like with the old csproj format. [There](https://github.com/CZEMacLeod/MSBuild.SDK.SystemWeb) you can file the documentation about this library.