# Difference between References and Dependencies in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, csproj

When I create a new ASP.NET Web Application in Visual Studio 2017, I end up with a Solution Explorer containing a `References` element.

[image]

When I create a new ASP.NET Core Web Application in Visual Studio 2017, I end up with a Solution Explorer containing a `Dependencies` element. Furthermore in this situation, NuGet didn't create local `packages` folder.

[image]

Why this difference? Is it possible to have this same `Dependencies` element with the ASP.Net Web Application solution?

Comment: .NETCore v5.0 was Microsoft's "yay, we get to do this all over again" moment.  They even changed the version number back to 1.  After which they discovered they had to do a lot of work to make it all the same again to get programmers to adopt it.

Comment: Dependencies is a better way to represent different types of references, so Microsoft makes it part of all SDK based new project types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why this difference ?

They are basically no different, they are used to store and manage references. Just as Lex said, the **Dependencies** is a better way to represent different types of references, we can clearly know where the reference comes from, SDK, nuget, etc. so that we can manage our references more efficiently.

See the info from [Introduction to ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#why-use-aspnet-core):

> ASP.NET Core is a redesign of ASP.NET 4.x, with architectural changes
>   that result in a leaner, more modular framework.

.

> Is it possible to have this same Dependencies element with the ASP.Net Web Application solution ?

Since there is still a bunch of open issues on GitHub regarding support of new csproj format for ASP.NET (non-Core) applications. We could not change the ASP.Net Web Application to the new project type, we could not have the same Dependencies element with the ASP.Net Web Application.

But if you are interested, you could check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47915353/can-the-new-csproj-file-structure-be-used-with-a-asp-net-framework-project) for how to convert to the new project type.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

**Display difference:**

The way you see your projects in the Solution Explorer depends on the format of their `.csproj` file.
In the old format (xml 2003 or similar) you have a `References` sub-tree, where every project reference, package dependency, system framework reference and third-party libraries are shown.

In the new format, you have a `Dependencies` sub-tree, which in turn has a sub-tree for every different type of dependency.

There are some differences as to how the two are implemented, but in general the only big difference (if you are not going into `.csproj` files and such) is how they are shown in the Solution Explorer.

Note that this display is **project dependent**, so you can have different displays for different projects in the same solution.

**NuGet packages:**

The difference in the usage and restoration of your NuGet packages comes from the following. The old format uses `packages.config` configuration by default, which means that every project holds all the packages in needs in a local cache.
On the other hand, the new format uses `Package Reference` configuration by default, where all the packages in the solution are restored to a central cache in the user directory (usually at `%user%/.nuget/packages`).